# Spanning the voltage gap between microprocessor and P-MOSFET

Tags: mosfet-driver, level-shifting

I need to control a high-side FET from an STM-8, to enable solar charging of 2x18650. The only pins I have left are PD4 and PD5 which are true open drain outputs: that would be perfect if I could use them to drive the P-MOSFET directly, but the pin voltage is limited to +6.5V, and my solar panel could supply up to 10V. The output does not have any protection diodes, and the STM8 spec states that *no injection current is allowed* for these pins.
[image]

The simplest circuit I can think of is this one, and it has a couple of disadvantages:

- the pull-up means that, if the microprocessor stops, charging is activated.
- the current is flowing through the pull-up resistor to the open-drain output any time when you are *not* charging, ie when you can least afford to waste current.

Is there a simpler alternative way to do this?

Comment: You could just use a low-side NMOS. Is there a reason you need the battery to be next to ground? Is it also powering your MCU?

Comment: @DKNguyen yes, the battery is powering the MCU.

Comment: Wouldn't you want the charger to regulate with a simple cct with the uC off as well as under uC control?  I have one  with hysteresis.  Also, what are the specs for your PV? And battery?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 the microprocessor should never be off. It implements a range of battery protection features, so if it's not running, no charging should take place. The batteries are 18650's the solar panel is a 3W unit, with maximum power at 9V. It can produce nearly11V with no load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not simpler, but you could do something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsMP3o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: you could but why

Comment: Because it solves both the problems mentioned by OP.

Answer (score 0):

The A03400 has a Vt of around 1V so this means you can drive it with >2x Vt or simply 3.3V or 5V or even 10V= V+ and 2V will make it work, so scale any input voltages to your expectations with a resistor divider.

FYI  Vmpt = 72 to 82% of V(open circuit) for dim to full sun.
So a good threshold is a resistor divider based on your battery voltage, load resistance and solar current ( with charge cutoff controls)

I would consider 2 Lithium cells with charge to 8.2V and cutoff at 5% of CC with hysteresis so Vbat must drop below 7.4V then Vpv rise above that threshold for charge to resume.

**Do you know how to design hysteresis with a threshold to control gate voltage relative to Vin and Vbat? ( with resistor ratios, a Vref and extra cct.)**

Input Vgs is rated for +/-15V.

See datasheet spec for Vgs(th) tolerances and current
Vgs(th) = Vt

For low inductance use short traces or twisted pairs.

Comment: I think that you have missed the point. The question is not about designing analog circuits to apply solar panel output and battery related charge thresholds, but about ways to drive a P-MOSFET from an open drain microprocessor output that cannot handle being pulled up to the  input voltage.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice: when the charging supply is of lower voltage than that of the battery, current can freely flow towards whatever solar circuitry is there via the pmos body diode. If you don't want that use back-to-back mosfets, or just a series diode.

The circuit you have drawn is pretty close to what is optimal in my opinion. The first issue you have with current consumption:

If the current draw of 100Kohms pull-up is that important, then just increase the resistance value. Depending on the leakage of the open drain output of the STM8 (lower then 1uA?), you can easily go up to 1Mohm of pull-up.

Another method is to derive the pull-up voltage from the charging supply itself. It won't consume any current from your own application. You'd only need to switch it when the supply is there right?

[image]

I added C1 for some extra noise immunity because I have no idea where Vcharge comes from. Also since you are switching a supply rail, it might be nice to have some protection on the gate so that any transients won't exceed maximum Vgs. Added that as well. Just check that your mosfet turns on sufficiently with -5Vgs, you can increase D1 zener voltage but that also means an extra part.

Also check if the STM8 can have a voltage on open-drain pins when it doesn't have power (if this can ever occur). If you have Vcharge but the STM8 has no power, it might violate the maximum ratings.
You can solve this issue by adding another nmos. This has the also benefit of inverting the operation so that the circuit won't activate the pmos when the open-drain is disabled (hi-z). The current through R4 would just be some leakage currents in that case when the open-drain is disabled.

[image]

Comment: There is a series diode to prevent reverse voltage into the MOSFET: I omitted it for clarity. As I said, VCharge comes from a solar panel, so noise should not be an issue. This circuit has the same disadvantage as mine: if the processor fails, charging will be enabled.

Comment: You cant have a single IO control pin for enabeling charging and have it be fail-safe for both open and short failure of the STM8 pin. I reversed it so it is a little bit better, per your request. You mentioned in another comment that the STM8 is handeling the battery protection, and you have a solar panels coming in straight to the battery? Not only is that very inefficient use of available solar power (consider MPPT dc/dc), it is also downright hazardous! Use a proper BMS or at least some kind of first level protection for OV, UV, OCD, OCC and short conditions. A fuse is nice as well.

Comment: an MPPT would be overkill for charging two 18650's: this setup is 80% efficient, and efficiency is irrelevant anyway when there is sunshine. Efficiency at night is the big issue. I omitted several other safety features for clarity: they cover all of the points that you mention, and more. I've tried commercial BMS chips and modules: the ST BC08 is perfect for 1s configurations  but, for small 2s systems, the ones I have tried are pants: lacking safety features, quirky, unreliable, dangerous. That's why I've built my own.

Comment: Hi, my apologies, I didn't realize you had these protections elsewhere in your system. It's true that there is a remarkable gap between 1S li-ion devices and anything beyond that. Once I have used the 2x BQ7791500PW for 8S protection and balancing, you could configure it for 2S but that wouldn't indeed be using the full  potential of that chip. Weird you found other devices to be quirky and unreliable. We used TI parts specific for that pack  because we needed EN62133 and DOT38 certification, and those tests are crazy demanding in terms of safety!

Comment: ...So having something with verified performance can give peace-of-mind and lower design time, since the manufacturers have put in so much time testing and developing. I But if it is not for commercial use that is perhaps not as interesting to you. Is there any BMS parts that have been troubling you like you pointed out? Or are you set on making  it yourself?

Comment: One example is the BQ29200, which does not check the temperature- an essential for any equipment that is in direct sunlight. An unventilated enclosure can easily exceed the maximum safe temperature for charging. I considered using a thermistor and comparator in addition to the BQ29200, but that's like having a dog and barking yourself. Also, it can get into some kind of latch-up state where it prevents charging even though both cells are below maximum. Standards compliance is not a big issue because these devices are for use in very remote locations. Reliability is an issue, though.